# How can I get DPKG in ubuntu to handle this packages.txt?

Tags: 14.04, cloning

I have a host machine, and a miner. The miner is trying to install a file called `packages.txt` via `dpkg` with the set selections and get-selections, and some sudo something `<($ cat packages.txt)` method I tried, and none of them worked.

```
apt-get install $(grep -vE "^\s*#" filename  | tr "\n" " ")
```

http://rs375.pbsrc.com/albums/oo199/Darlok1983/20170316_120956_zpszwupoe4r.jpg?w=280&h=210&fit=crop

Comment: Please don't post screenshots (or worse, photos) of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

for i in $(cat ~/Desktop/install.txt)
do
  if [ $i != "install" ]
  then
    dpkg -i /location/$i #or any other command...
  fi
done
```

Comment: try it with an echo command if it does the job...